# Systems of Equation Review Question. Setting them equal to each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If I have two equations:
$$y-2x=0$$ and
$$x-2y=0$$

As they both equal zero, why can't I set them equal to each other and get $y-2x=x-2y$ which means $x=y$?

I know one can't do this, but I forgot why.

Thanks!

Comment: That's allowed and perfectly valid. It is in fact equivalent to subtracting the two equations. You'll still need to substitute $x=y$ back into one of the equations to solve the system.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's not my end point, I then use that to sub back into the equation. Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, that is perfectly valid.
Think about it like this, you have four numbers:
$$a=y,b=-2x,c=x,d=-2y$$
such that
$$a+b=0,c+d=0\\\implies a+b=c+d$$
There is no issue here.
However if you have a situation with four numbers $a,b,c,d$ and a relation like this:
$$ab=0\\cd=0$$
it is still fine to assume that $ab=cd$ (as this just implies $0=0$ which is true) but you can't use it to derive information regarding $a,b,c,d$ unless you know one
or more non-zero values of them.
Say you knew that $a=c=0$, you can't use this to show that $b=d$ because such a process would involve dividing by 0. In your situation you're not multiplying unknowns so you shouldn't have an issue with it.